# Is it possible to set the standard input/output to a file in C?

Tags: c, file-io

Can the standard input/output be set to a file for a C programme. I know that we can use fscanf and fprintf to read from and write to a file but by setting the std i/o to a file, can we use just printf/scanf for i/o operations in a C programme?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is it possible to set the standard input/output to a file in C?

Yes, you can do that using [`freopen`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/freopen).

Example code from the above site:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    puts("stdout is printed to console");
    if (freopen("redir.txt", "w", stdout) == NULL)
    {
       perror("freopen() failed");
       return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    puts("stdout is redirected to a file"); // this is written to redir.txt
    fclose(stdout);
}
```